# SecurityException: Calling uid does not have permission to access picker uri

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-storage

I'm using

```
fun Context.persistUriAccess(uri: Uri) {
    grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}
```

to access images from the gallery after the user picked them using `PickVisualMedia()`.

Everything works until I uninstall and reinstall the app

After that, I can't access the images anymore:

```
SecurityException: Calling uid ( 10575 ) does not have permission to access picker uri: content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000012483
```

I tried to go *"All in! Let's ask for the whole thing!"*

```
    private fun accessGallery() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            requestPermissions.launch(arrayOf(READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED))
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            requestPermissions.launch(arrayOf(READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO))
        } else {
            requestPermissions.launch(arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        }
    }
```

as stated here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access, but I still get the `SecurityException` and no image on screen.

How am I supposed to do this? I would rather not make copies of the images and ship them to my BE only to download them every time I want to show them

Comment: Yes if you uninstall your app the persisted permissions are gone too.

Comment: `grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.....` Remove that line as it does nothing and is only confusing.

Comment: Where are you storing the Uri such that you have access to it after you've uninstalled and reinstalled the app? Are you storing Uris on your backend? Or is this a database you've chosen to back up? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier; I don't use the bird site much anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> How am I supposed to do this?

To some extent, the answer is: hope the user does not uninstall and reinstall the app. If you are anticipating that this will happen a lot, that seems like a problem to try to solve.

The `Uri` values are useless except for this app installation. Once the app is uninstalled, any permissions associated with those `Uri` values go "poof".

Storing such `Uri` values is fine for a "link" sort of operation, where you are in position to deal with broken links for any reason. For example, the user could delete the image; my assumption is that your app will similarly break for that scenario, if you try to use a `Uri` that points to the now-deleted image. Once you figure out what sort of UX you want to have for this scenario, you can decide if it could be extended for the uninstall/reinstall scenario.

If you determine that you cannot cope with the deleted-image case, then you have more of an "import" operation, where you need to make your own copy of the content and work with that copy that you control. And, if you want to extend that approach to handle uninstall/reinstall, you will need to "make copies of the images and ship them to my BE".

> only to download them every time I want to show them

So, cache them:

- When the user imports an image into your app, copy it to your cache and arrange to upload it to your BE
- If you have a reference to an image that is not cached locally (uninstall/reinstall, cache eviction policy, "clear data" in Settings, etc.), download it from the BE into the cache

In the ideal case, the user *never* downloads the image, as they just use the cached copy.